# Why is the statement, inside a thread, not working?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, python-2.7, archlinux

The button is working but the threading is not working at all. What is causing it to fail?
`thread.start_new_thread(task1)` statement is not executed.

/var/tmp/p.py:

```
import sys,os
import pygtk, gtk, gobject
import socket, datetime, threading
import ConfigParser
import urllib2
import subprocess
import threading
import thread

# Singleton run once
import fcntl, sys
pid_file = '/var/tmp/program.pid'
fp = open(pid_file, 'w')
try:
  fcntl.lockf(fp, fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
except IOError:
  # another instance is running
  sys.exit(0)

# Read config file
server="http://blabla"
username="stackoverflow"
password="freak"
language="EN"    
# Disconnect
get_disconnect="/a/disconnectusername?username=%s&password=%s&language=%s" % (username,password,language)
disconnect_url="%s%s" % (server,get_disconnect)

# Do multi-thread without blocking the main front-end
def task1():
  urllib2.urlopen(disconnect_url)

class GTK_Main:

  def __init__(self):
    # main GTK
    self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
    self.window.set_size_request(1280, 720)
    self.window.set_border_width(10)
    self.window.set_decorated(False)
    self.window.set_title("Test")
    self.window.move(0,0)
    self.window.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit, "WM destroy")

    hbox = gtk.HBox(False, 0)
    self.vbox.pack_start(hbox, False)    
    hbox.set_border_width(10)
    hbox.pack_start(gtk.Label(), True, True, 0)

    # Disconnect
    self.button_disconnect = gtk.Button()
    self.button_disconnect.set_name("disconnectButton")
    self.button_disconnect.connect("clicked", self.disconnectButton)    
    hbox.pack_start(self.button_disconnect, False)   

    hbox.add(gtk.Label())    
    self.window.show_all()
    self.window.set_keep_above(True)

    if(self.window.get_window().get_state() == gtk.gdk.WINDOW_STATE_MAXIMIZED):
      print "unmaximize"
      self.window.unmaximize()


  def disconnectButton(self, w):
    print "Window Resize"
    #subprocess.call("java -cp /var/tmp/dist/Audio.jar ui.Connecting1 wait..", shell=True)
    #urllib2.urlopen(disconnect_url)
    try:
      #t1 = threading.Thread(target=task1)
      #t1.start()
      thread.start_new_thread(task1)
    except:
      print "Error: threading.."

    subprocess.call("/var/tmp/runme.sh", shell=True)

try:
  GTK_Main()
  gtk.gdk.threads_init()
  gtk.main()
except (SystemExit, KeyboardInterrupt):
  sock.close()
  gtk.main_quit()
```

/var/tmp/runme.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=:0.0
# kill please
ps aux | grep p.py | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9;
sleep 2
# kill please
ps aux | grep p.py | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9;
sleep 2
# kill for sure please
ps aux | grep p.py | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9;
# cross finger and run now
python /var/tmp/p.py &
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because

1) you are running multi-thread to crawl web link, but we link will take some time to give packets back, there is a duration need to be wait...

2) immediately you are killing the python and restarting it, as a result it kills the thread, which represent that it was not working

3) to resolve this kind of issue use

```
  t1 = threading.Thread(target=task1)
  t1.start()
  t1.join() # this tells to wait until job is done (url crawl)

  #thread.start_new_thread(task1)
```